# InMemoryConnection Elasticsearch jsonSerializationException in nest version 6.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

With NEST version 6.x and NEST.JSonSerializer version 6.x, I am getting JSONSerialization exception, with inMemory elasticsearch for unit test.

I tried with Nest and JsonSersializer versions 7.x, and it was working fine. But my production server has 6.x versions, so I need to run the test on 6.x NEST Client.

```
    var response = new
    {
        took = 1,
        timed_out = false,
        _shards = new
            {
                total = 2,
                successful = 2,
                failed = 0
            },
                hits = new
                {
                    total = new { value = 25 },
                    max_score = 1.0,
                    hits = Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Select(i => (object)new
                    {
                        _index = "project",
                        _type = "project",
                        _id = $"Project {i}",
                        _score = 1.0,
                        _source = new { name = $"Project {i}" }
                    }).ToArray()
                    }
     };

    var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
    var connection = new InMemoryConnection(responseBytes, 200);
    var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool,connection).DefaultIndex("project");
        settings.DisableDirectStreaming();
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(s => s.MatchAll());
```

**Expected output:** response from inMemory elasticsearch
**Getting Error:**
        JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Int64' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Schema of total part in the response body changed between versions [6.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-body.html) and [7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-track-total-hits) of elasticsearch. If you want to make your response body working with NEST 6.x you will need to change total part from

```
..
total = new { value = 25 },
..
```

to

```
..
total = 25,
..
```

Full example:

```
var response = new
{
    took = 1,
    timed_out = false,
    _shards = new
    {
        total = 2,
        successful = 2,
        failed = 0
    },
    hits = new
    {
        total = 25,
        max_score = 1.0,
        hits = Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Select(i => (object)new
        {
            _index = "project",
            _type = "project",
            _id = $"Project {i}",
            _score = 1.0,
            _source = new { name = $"Project {i}" }
        }).ToArray()
    }
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks (y)... It worked for me...Now i am able to get data without any exception.